# How to automatically shut down an JMXConnectorServer

Tags: java, jmx

I'm trying to start a JMXConnectorServer for management and debug purposes. But I don't want this service to prevent application from exiting normally when the last non-daemon thread is terminated.

In other words, I want the following program to terminate immediately:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL("rmi", null, 0);
        JMXConnectorServer connectorServer =
            JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(jmxUrl, null, mbs);
        connectorServer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String port = getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port");
if (port == null) {
    port = String.valueOf(getAvailablePort());
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port", port);
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl", "false");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate", "false");

    sun.management.Agent.startAgent();
}
log.info(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() + ":" + port);
```

Comment: These are two answers in one, right? Which one did solve the problem for you? You could make this clear by posting two answers and accepting the one you like better.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you will need to so a `connectorServer.stop();` at some point.

**Edit:**

In reading your comments, it sounds like you should do something like:

```
connectorServer.start();
try {
    // create thread-pool
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors...
    // submit jobs to the thread-pool
    ...
    threadPool.shutdown();
    // wait for the submitted jobs to finish
    threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_LONG, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} finally {
    connectorServer.stop();
}
```

@Nicholas' idea of the shutdown hook is a good one.  Typically, however, I had my `main` thread wait on some sort of variable that is set from a `shutdown()` JMX operation.  Something like:

```
public CountDownLatch shutdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
...

// in main
connectorServer.start();
try {
    // do the main-thread stuff
    shutdownLatch.await();
} finally {
    connectorServer.stop();
}

// in some JMX exposed operation
public void shutdown() {
    Main.shutdownLatch.countDown();
}
```

As an aside, you could use my [SimpleJMX](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) package to manage your JMX server for you.

```
JmxServer jmxServer = new JmxServer(8000);
jmxServer.start();
try {
    // register our lookupCache object defined below
    jmxServer.register(lookupCache);
    jmxServer.register(someOtherObject);
} finally {
    jmxServer.stop();
}
```

Comment: My application is complicated. It starts thread pool doing processing in multiply threads. I can't deal with latch. All I want is RMI Accept Tread to be daemon.

Comment: How does the application know to shutdown @MykhayloAdamovych?  Does it receive a message or something?  Whatever is supposed to shut your application down should call the `shutdown()` method.

Comment: Application is shutdown 'normally' when last non-daemon thread exits.

Comment: Sure.  When do you want your application to shutdown @MykhayloAdamovych?  Obviously you don't want your main to exit and stop the application.  What is the last non-daemon thread running and how does it know to exit?

Comment: I want main (non-daemon) to start thread pool (muliply non-daemon threads) process data in a day or so... and exit normally. Don't want to shutdownt it by hand. Last non-daemon thread is last working the thread from thread pool. Within that I want to monitor what is going on inside...

Comment: So I would have your main start the threads in a thread-pool and then do an `threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_LONG, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`.  After that finishes, all of your jobs should be done.  Then main can stop the `connectorServer` and exit.

Answer (score 1):

I play with similar issue and wrote this class:

```
public final class HardDaemonizer extends Thread {

    private final Runnable target;
    private final String newThreadName;

    public HardDaemonizer(Runnable target, String name, String newThreadName) {
        super(name == null ? "Daemonizer" : name);
        setDaemon(true);
        this.target = target;
        this.newThreadName = newThreadName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            List<Thread> tb = getSubThreads();
            target.run();
            List<Thread> ta = new java.util.ArrayList<>(getSubThreads());
            ta.removeAll(tb);
            for (Thread thread : ta) {
                thread.setName(newThreadName);
            }
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HardDaemonizer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static Thread daemonize(String daemonizerName, String newThreadName, Runnable target) {
        HardDaemonizer daemonizer = new HardDaemonizer(target, daemonizerName, newThreadName);
        daemonizer.start();
        return daemonizer;
    }

    private static List<Thread> getSubThreads() {
        ThreadGroup group = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getParent();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[group.activeCount()];
        group.enumerate(threads);
        return java.util.Arrays.asList(threads);
    }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
HardDaemonizer.daemonize(null, "ConnectorServer", new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            connectorServer.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ralph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Be careful - it's tricky!

---

**EDIT**

Agh... It's not solution for you. It hard-daemonize connector thread only and this thread will be killed when jvm stops. Additionaly you can customize name of this thread.

Alternatively you can add flag `completed` and sleep in loop in `daemonize` method until connector server start up.

---

**SIMPLIFIED**

This is simplified daemonizer without tricky thread renaming:

```
public abstract class Daemonizer<T> extends Thread {

    private final T target;
    private boolean completed = false;
    private Exception cause = null;

    public Daemonizer(T target) {
        super(Daemonizer.class.getSimpleName());
        setDaemon(true);
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            act(target);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            cause = ex;
        }
        completed = true;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Daemonizer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public abstract void act(final T target) throws Exception;

    public static void daemonize(Daemonizer daemonizer) throws Exception {
        daemonizer.start();
        while (!daemonizer.completed) {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
        if (daemonizer.cause != null) {
            throw daemonizer.cause;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Daemonizer.daemonize(new Daemonizer<JMXConnectorServer>(server) {
    @Override
    public void act(JMXConnectorServer server) throws Exception {
        server.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [JVM Shutdown Hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to stop the connector server.

**===== UPDATE =====**

Not sure why your shutdown hook doesn't work. Perhaps you can supply your sample code. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    try {
        log("Creating Connector Server");
        final JMXConnectorServer jcs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(new JMXServiceURL("rmi", "localhost", 12387), null, ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
        Thread jcsStopper = new Thread("JCS-Stopper") {
            public void run() {
                if(jcs.isActive()) {
                    try {
                        jcs.stop();
                        log("Connector Server Stopped");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log("Failed to stop JCS");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                       
                }
            }
        };
        jcsStopper.setDaemon(false);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(jcsStopper);
        log("Registered Server Stop Task");
        jcs.start();
        log("Server Started");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.exit(0);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
[main]:Creating Connector Server
[main]:Registered Server Stop Task
[main]:Server Started
[JCS-Stopper]:Connector Server Stopped
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Shutdown Hook newer called for me in this situation. Could you please provide an example that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the `JMXConnectorServer` is only running in a user thread when you create it explicitly.

If you instead configure RMI access for the platform MBean server via system properties, the implicitly created JMX connector server will run as daemon process and not prevent the JMV shutdown. To do this, your code would shrink to the following

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    }
}
```

but you'll need to set the following system properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1919
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```